# disable extraction from jar file in java

Tags: java, swing, jar, inno-setup, executable-jar

I want to make setup file for java swing application .

I am creating the setup by writing the script file and selecting the source file as jar and other necessary resources .

Now i want to make my jar disable to extraction .

Is there any way from which i make sure so that no can access the resources from my jar file either the class files or images etc.

thanks in advance

Comment: How is this related to inno-setup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make it harder to get your resources, but you can't make it impossible. That's not a Java problem, by the way, but a general one of distributed software. In order to access your resources, your program (or in the case of Java the runtime environment) must be able to unpack them. Even when you encrypt them somehow, the program needs to include the decryption key and the decryption algorithms. A determined user can find these through reverse engineering, and use them to get your resources.

Answer (score 1):

You could try obfuscating your codes.

This is the one I have used for obfuscate.

```
 http://www.zelix.com/klassmaster/
```

You could find more tools for that.

Answer (score -1):

You can use java webstart, your jars will be kept in cache so very its hard to access.

[Java Web Start Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/contents.html)

Comment: any user who knows what he is doing knows where to find the java webstart cache.

Comment: @Philipp can find path but will be able to make it jar back ?

Comment: The user doesn't even need to do that, because you have to put the jar file on a webserver accessible to the user for WebStart to work.

Comment: @Philipp yes I knew, I suggested a way of deployment. thats it.